# GeneXus + IOS requerimentos/complexidade para funcionar

Tags: ios, genexus

Alguem sabe de alguma documentação para gerar apps para IOS utilizando genexus,
quais requerimentos e configurações devo fazer? é muito complexo configurar tudo para fazer rodar legal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode começar aqui: [My first Apple app](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?14738) (documento em Inglês)

Para iniciar o desenvolvimento tem duas opções:

1. Usar o KBN para prototipagem, você precisa de um dispositivo iOS
2. Usar uma Mac para compilar o aplicativo

A segunda opção é necessária para publicar o aplicativo na App Store

Answer (score 0):

A documentação adequada para **iOS** é 
[http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?iOS+Requirements,](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?iOS%20Requirements,)

E para não precisar ter uma conta de desenvolvedor na Apple enquanto testa, e se não tiver um Macbook para prototipo, você pode instalar o MacOS numa VM (recomendo ***Oracle VM VirtualBox***) em qualquer computador com Windows 64-bits.

Boa sorte!